# Proving a topology generated from a basis is the smallest topology

Tags: general-topology

The question: Given $X$ is a topological space, with a basis $\mathcal B$ generating a topology $\mathcal T$, I am trying to prove that this topology is the smallest topology on $X$ that contains $\mathcal B$ (i.e all other topologies are more fine than this one).

I am attempting to prove via contradiction.
First, I assumed that there exists some topology $\mathcal J$ that contains $\mathcal B$ such that $\mathcal J \subset \mathcal T$, implying that $\mathcal T$ is more fine. This implies that there exists some subset $\mathcal J \not\ni t \in \mathcal T$. Then, by definition, $t \in \mathcal T \Rightarrow \forall x \in t, x \in b \subset t$ for some $b \in \mathcal B$. This implies that $t \subset \bigcup  b$ (for $b \in \mathcal B$) and given that $\mathcal J$ contains $\mathcal B$, by the definition of a topology, $\bigcup b \in \mathcal J$.  At this point, I have a hunch that I should consider the set $(t \cap \bigcup  b)$ and maybe its complement, but I am not sure how to proceed. (I want to conclude that given the assumption, $t$ is also in $\mathcal J$ (letting me conclude). Is this the right way to approach this problem? Or is there a more clever way?

Comment: As $b\subseteq t$ for each $b$ then $\cup b\subseteq t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what is being claimed here. Let $\tau$ be the topology generated by basis $\mathcal{B}$, and let $\mu$ be another topology containing $\mathcal{B}$. You need to show that $\tau \subseteq \mu$.

Recall also that $\tau$ is the set of all unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. That is, a general element $\mathcal{V} \in \tau$ has the form
$$\mathcal{V} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{U}_\alpha,$$
where $A$ is some arbitrary index set, and $\mathcal{U}_\alpha \in \mathcal{B}$ for all $\alpha \in A$.

So, you need to show that all such $\mathcal{V}$ also lies in $\mu$.

This is true, because $\mu$ contains everything in $\mathcal{B}$, including each $\mathcal{U}_\alpha$, and further, $\mu$ is closed under arbitrary unions (axiomatically). So, indeed $\mathcal{V} \in \mu$, and $\tau \subseteq \mu$.

Conclusion: every topology that contains $\mathcal{B}$ contains $\tau$, so $\tau$ is the smallest topology to contain $\mathcal{B}$.